# Azure CLI task "az sf cluster create" fails with hosted agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-cli

The following command is based on a code snippet I found in the official documentation to create a Linux Service Fabric cluster.

Originally it was bash script, but that's not available on my private build agents (requires windows insider program??) so I switched to batch script.

**I wonder why the following command fails:**

```
d:\a\r1\a>call az sf cluster create --resource-group "ha17aztestclustergroup"  --location "westeurope"  --certificate-output-folder . --certificate-password "433q6D7sdNKkd-.,6ck@6"  --certificate-subject-name "ha17rsomaztestsf.cloudapp.azure.com"  --cluster-name "ha17aztestcluster"  --cluster-size 3 --os UbuntuServer1604 --vault-name "ha17rsomaztestkeyvault"  --vault-resource-group "ha17aztestclustergroup"  --vm-password $VmPassword --vm-user-name "sfadmin" 
ERROR: az sf cluster: error: argument subcommand: invalid choice: create
usage: az sf cluster [-h]
                      {select,manifest,code-version,config-version,health} ...
```

**The exact same inline script does work on my private build agents** with AZ CLI 2.0.20 installed.

Azure hosted Agents (VS2017) has AZ CLI 2.0.14 installed.
But I doubt that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hosted VS2017 has Azure CLI 2.0.14 installed, there isn’t **create** command for az sf cluster (2.0.21 contains), you can check it by adding **Azure CLI** task with a`z sf cluster --help` command to check its commands.

So, you can setup a private build agent and do build with this agent. [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem whilst deploying a different resource (Function Apps). There was a bug fix in a later version than what was installed on the hosted agents.

I ended up getting around this problem by either dynamically injecting this command into my scripts or by simply having an extra Azure CLI step in my Release to update Azure CLI

`pip install --pre azure-cli --extra-index-url https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/edge`

Unfortunately it takes nearly 5 minutes to update the Agent but all of my Releases are reliable now.